# Formula for number of "root" nodes in a tree where Parent shares child nodes?

Tags: trees

If I have a tree like this:

{a},{b,c},{d,e,f},{g,h,i,j}

in this case we have a total of 10 nodes. Is there any equation where given "10" I can calculate how many bottom nodes there are (answer: "4" in my example)?

Comment: I don't understand the tree structure. What you're calling "bottom nodes" are typically called "leaf nodes," I think, but I could be wrong. Is the idea that each node has 0, 1, or 2 kids, and $a$ has children $b,c$, with $b$ having kids $d,e$ and $c$ having child $f$, and then ... no...I just don't get it. Can I suggest a notation like `{a -> b, c}, {b -> d, e}, {c -> f}, {d -> g,h}, ...` as a way to make the graph stucture clearer to us?

Comment: Did you perhaps mean a 'pyramid' of numbers ($1$ on the top row, $2$ on the second row, ...) like in [Pascals triange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle) rather than a [tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28graph_theory%29)?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that the $n$th triangular number is given by:
$$
T_n = \frac{n(n + 1)}{2}
$$
You appear to be asking for the inverse of this function. By taking the positive version of the above function's inverse, we obtain the following formula:
$$
\frac{\sqrt{8n + 1} - 1}{2}
$$

Indeed, for $n = 10$ nodes, we find that the number of levels is:
$$
\frac{\sqrt{8(10) + 1} - 1}{2} = \frac{\sqrt{81} - 1}{2} = \frac{8}{2} = 4
$$
as desired.

Comment: out of curiousity how did you arrive at the second equation, from the first?

Comment: It's found by applying the quadratic formula to:
$$
n = \frac{y(y + 1)}{2} \iff \frac{1}{2}y^2 + \frac{1}{2}y - n = 0
$$
in order to solve for $y$ in terms of $n$.